# Multiple sets of criteria to subset python dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small data set that I am trying to filter out to create an even smaller dataframe. The issue I'm having is I don't know how to get the sets of criteria nested inside one another to work correctly.

The code below is the closest I have been able to get. It should be looking in the larger data frame with columns for 'material', 'waterbody', and 'mosscat'; and only returning those that satisfy the combination of stone, marsh, and average OR brick, river, average.

```
dfy = dfx[
    (dfx['material']=='stone') &
    (dfx['waterbody']=='marsh') &
    (dfx['mosscat']=='average'),
    (dfx['material']=='brick') &
    (dfx['waterbody']=='river') &
    (dfx['mosscat']=='average')]
```

Comment: `dfy = dfx[(dfx['material']=='stone')&(dfx['waterbody']=='marsh')&(dfx['mosscat']=='average')|
(dfx['material']=='brick')&(dfx['waterbody']=='river')&(dfx['mosscat']=='average')]`?

Answer (score 0):

Making your code readable makes it easier to see your mistakes.  I edited your question to add whitespace, now let's edit some more to fix it:

```
isStoneMarsh = dfx['material'] == 'stone' & dfx['waterbody'] == 'marsh'
isBrickRiver = dfx['material'] == 'brick' & dfx['waterbody'] == 'river'
isAverage = dfx['mosscat'] == 'average'
dfy = dfx[(isStoneMarsh | isBrickRiver) & isAverage]
```

I lifted `isAverage` up a level so it's only evaluated once.